# The Airy functions and miscellaneous sequences of odd integers without repeated prime factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples, integers, prime-factorization, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm curious about the following miscellaneous conjectures, for which I hope that one can to get a counterexample.

I add the encyclopedia Wikipedia's article for the [*Airy functions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) $\operatorname{Ai}(x)$ and $\operatorname{Bi}(x)$, and we denote the floor function as $\lfloor x\rfloor$. Then playing with Wolfram Alpha online calculator I've defined two miscellaneous sequences.

**Definition.** For integers $n\geq 1$ we define the sequences of integers $$a_n=-4+\biggl\lfloor\frac{1}{\operatorname{Ai}(n)-\operatorname{Ai}(n+1)}\biggr\rfloor,$$
and $$b_n=-2+\biggl\lfloor \operatorname{Bi}(n+1)-\operatorname{Bi}(n)\biggr\rfloor.$$

(From few computational evidence, the calculations that I got) I've consider the following conjecture.

**Conjectures.** *If*  $a_n\equiv 1\text{ mod }2$, *then this odd integer* $a_n$ *has no repeated prime factors.* *And similarly, if* $b_n\equiv 1\text{ mod }2$, *then this odd integer* $b_n$ *has no repeated prime factors.*

> **Question.** I'm curious to know what is the smallest counterexample for each of previous miscellaneous conjectures. I think that it should be possible to find a counterexample, any case feel free to add if there is some reasoning or heuristic to find the counterexamples that I evoke. **Many thanks and good day.**

Comment: Many thanks for the upvotes. If some user cann't find counterexamples for a big segment of integers I would like to know it.